# How do I access the Notification (foundation class) and not my (custom class named Notification)?

Tags: ios, swift, observers

Problem is, I want to create an extension on my Extension file something like below.

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let value = Notification.Name(rawValue: "value")
}
```

But unfortunately, it is reading my custom class named Notification, and I just want to access directly to the foundation this time... so I can go to .Name

Is there some way like mentions as in android like @DoNotReadCustomClass just besides the method? haha or something like that?

@onlyGoForFundationClass?
@exeptionForThisTimeOnCustomClass or something like that?

thanks.

Comment: Rename your custom class. It's bad practice to *override* system structs/classes

Comment: good advice! thanks. Appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prefix it with the name of the module that declares the class. In this case it would be:

```
extension Foundation.Notification.Name {
    static let value = Foundation.Notification.Name(rawValue: "value")
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I already renamed the class, but I didn't know that tip! Appreciated!